# Custom Path database in android

Tags: android

I want open a custom path, create a database, create a table and insert values.

```
public class MySQLiteOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    MySQLiteOpenHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, "/mnt/sdcard/database_name.db", null, 0);
    }
}

public class DBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public Context context;
    public static final String DATABASE_PATH=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/WebService/Databases/";
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME="database_name.db";

    public DBHandler(Context context){
        //Create the Database
        super(context, DATABASE_PATH+DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
        this.context=context;
        Log.i("databaseService","Database Created ");
    }
}
```

---

Stacktrace:

```
E/SQLiteLog: (14) cannot open file at line 35807 of [553a923c82]
(14) os_unix.c:35807: (2) open(/storage/emulated/0/WebService/Databases/database_name.db) - 
E/SQLiteDatabase: Failed to open database '/storage/emulated/0/WebService/Databases/database_name.db'.
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:211)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:195)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:493)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:200)
```

Comment: Does your app request permission to [write to external storage](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files#WriteExternalStorage)?

Comment: "yes , i tried in mainActivity"

Comment: Ok, can you post your permission code from MainActivity? Can you confirm that the permission code works? If you go to your app's permissions page within Android Settings, is the External Storage option ticked?

Comment: "Yes , my apps permission is ticked"